# Not able to get the URL parameter in apex controller using Apex.currenPage().getParameters()

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I am working on a visualforce page where on click of a button i am passing some parameters in URL and fetching that in controller using `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get()` method.

But I am not able to get the city parameter in the below URL.

what am I doing wrong?

URL:https://c.cs51.visual.force.com/apex/emailClient?streetAdd=2711+Avenue+X+&leadID=00Q4B000003KWwcUAG#5G&City=Brooklyn

```
public with sharing class SendEmailController {

    public String addlRecipients {get; set;}
    public Lead   ourLead {get; set;}
    public EmailMessage emailMsg {get; private set;}
    public String FromAddress {get;set;}
    public string StreetAddress {get;set;}
    public string cityName {get;set;}



    public SendEmailController() {

        //Getting all the parameters from the URL.
        String streetAdd = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('streetAdd');
        if(streetAdd != null){
            StreetAddress = streetAdd;
        }

        string city = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('City');
          system.debug('city city'+city);
        if(city !=null){          
            cityName = city;    
        }
        system.debug('city param'+cityName);
        String leadID = ApexPAges.currentPage().getParameters().get('leadID');
        if(leadID != null)
            ourLead = [select id,name,Email from lead where id =:leadID];
        FromAddress = 'Sample@movoto.com';
        emailMsg = new EmailMessage();


    }

    public Attachment attachment {
        get {
            if (attachment==null) {
                System.debug('==========> creating new empty Attachment.');
                attachment = new Attachment();
            }
            return attachment;
        }
        set;
    }

    // send email message per the attributes specified by a user.
    public PageReference send() {
        try {
            // now create our SingleEmailMessage to send out.
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleEmailMsg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            // concatenate all Bcc Addresses
            if (emailMsg.BccAddress != null && emailMsg.BccAddress != '') {
                singleEmailMsg.setBccAddresses(emailMsg.BccAddress.split(';'));
            }

            // concatenate all CC Addresses
            if (emailMsg.CcAddress != null && emailMsg.CcAddress != '') {
                singleEmailMsg.setCcAddresses(emailMsg.CcAddress.split(';'));
            }

            singleEmailMsg.setSubject(emailMsg.Subject);
            singleEmailMsg.setPlainTextBody(emailMsg.TextBody);
            singleEmailMsg.setTargetObjectId(ourLead.id);
            singleEmailMsg.setSaveAsActivity(true); // Save this email as an acitvity in activity history.

            // now add additional recipients
            String[] addlToAddresses = null;
            if (addlRecipients != null && addlRecipients != '') {
                addlToAddresses = addlRecipients.split(';');
            }
            // now lets add any additional recipients to our list of recipients.
            List<String> lstToAddresses = null;
            if (addlToAddresses != null) {
                // now append these to our main recipient.
                lstToAddresses = new List<String>(addlToAddresses);
            } else {
                lstToAddresses = new List<String>();
            }
            lstToAddresses.add(emailMsg.ToAddress);
            singleEmailMsg.setToAddresses(lstToAddresses); 

            // now we need to reset the ToAddress for our EmailMessage.
            emailMsg.ToAddress += (addlRecipients != null ? ';' + addlRecipients : '');

            if (attachment.Body != null) {
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment emailAttachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                emailAttachment.setBody(attachment.Body);
                emailAttachment.setFileName(attachment.Name);
                singleEmailMsg.setFileAttachments(new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> {emailAttachment});
            }
            List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results =  Messaging.sendEmail(
                new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {singleEmailMsg});

            // now parse  our results

            if (results[0].success) {

                if (attachment.Body != null) {
                    attachment.parentId=emailMsg.Id;
                    insert attachment;
                }

                PageReference pgRef = new PageReference('/' + ourLead.Id);
                pgRef.setRedirect(true);
                return pgRef;
            } else {
                // on failure, display error message on existing page so return null to return there.
                String errorMsg = 'Error sending Email Message. Details = ' + results.get(0).getErrors()[0].getMessage();
                System.debug('==========> ' + errorMsg);
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, errorMsg));
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // on failure, display error message on existing page so return null to return there.
            String errorMsg = 'Exception thrown trying to send Email Message. Details = ' + e;
            System.debug('==========> ' + errorMsg);
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, errorMsg));
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }

    // cancel creation of emailMessage. 
    public PageReference cancel() {
        // no need to do anything - just return to calling page.
        PageReference pgRef = new PageReference('/' + ourLead.Id);
        pgRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pgRef;
    }


    public PageReference populateTemplate() {
        // we need to perform the merge for this email template before displaying to end-user.

        EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [select Body, HtmlValue, Subject, DeveloperName, BrandTemplateId 
                                       from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName='Brokerage_email_template' limit 1];

        // construct dummy email to have Salesforce merge BrandTemplate (HTML letterhead) with our email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage dummyEmailMsg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        dummyEmailMsg.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);
        // This ensures that sending this email is not saved as an activity for the targetObjectId. 
        dummyEmailMsg.setSaveAsActivity(false);

        // send dummy email to populate HTML letterhead in our EmailMessage object's HTML body.
        String[] toAddresses = new String[]{FromAddress};
            dummyEmailMsg.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

        Account dummyAcct = new Account(Name='dummy account');
        insert dummyAcct;

        Contact dummyContact        = new Contact(AccountId=dummyAcct.Id);
        dummyContact.FirstName      = 'First';
        dummyContact.LastName       = 'Last';
        dummyContact.Email          = 'nobody@nowhere.com';
        insert dummyContact;

        dummyEmailMsg.setTargetObjectId(dummyContact.Id);
        dummyEmailMsg.setWhatId(ourLead.Id);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {dummyEmailMsg});
        // now rollback our changes.
        Database.rollback(sp);

        String body = dummyEmailMsg.getPlainTextBody();

          system.debug('cityy::'+cityName);
           system.debug('stdd::'+StreetAddress);

        if(!String.isBlank(StreetAddress) && StreetAddress!= 'null')
            body = body.replace('ADDR ', StreetAddress);
         else{
              body = body.replace('ADDR ', ' ');
         } 
          if(cityName!=null && cityName != 'null') { 
           body = body.replace('CITYR', cityName);
            }
            else
            {
                 body = body.replace('CITYR', ' ');
            }
            body = body.replace('ClientName', ourLead.name);



        // now populate our fields with values from SingleEmailMessage.
        emailMsg.BccAddress  = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
        emailMsg.Subject     = dummyEmailMsg.getSubject();
        emailMsg.TextBody    = body;
        emailMsg.ToAddress   = ourLead.email;
        emailMsg.FromAddress = fromAddress; 
        emailMsg.CcAddress   = '';

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `#5G` before City parameter in url and try.

Comment: It works after removing `#5G` from the URL parameter. Is there any reason for appending that in URL?

Comment: URL accept certain valid character in query parameters, always good to encode them before redirection.

Comment: @reshma .that #5G is coming from streetAdd parameter.do we have any limit on number of characters that a param value can have?

Comment: There are no salesforce limits for no of characters passed as parameters. But you should aware of browser URL length limits. If `#5G` is part of streetAdd param then how its coming after leadId param? Please ensure url parameters are encoded properly to make it works fine.

Comment: Anything after the **#** in the URL is not sent to server by the browser that's why you are not getting value for the _City_ parameter;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value after the hash mark or anchor as shown in a user's browser: This isn't possible with "standard" HTTP as this value is never sent to the server (hence it won't be available in `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get()`). You would need some sort of JavaScript magic on the client side, e.g. to include this value as a POST parameter or remove this and add to the main URL.

Credit: [sfussenegger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317523/2922854)

Answer (score 0):

We can do it via javascript-

```
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url) url = window.location.href;
             name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) 
                return null;
            if (!results[2]) 
                return '';

            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Call this function - For eg: If you are passing a variable by the name of id we can get it by using

JavaScrprit

```
var GetIdFromUrl = getParameterByName('id');
```